# how can i variable to method name in parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

i try to call a method dynamically in other method, but this code dosn't work. how can i do it ?

```
#region Form1_Load()
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Load();
    //this line 
    InitTimer(this.Form1_Load(sender,e));
}
#endregion

#region Timer()
public void InitTimer(dynamic _method)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
    timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(_method);
    timer1.Interval = 5000; // in miliseconds
    timer1.Start();
}
#endregion
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What specific error do you receive?

Comment: It looks like you'll get an infinite recursion here since you're calling `Form1_Load` within itself, and it will be evaluated before `InitTimer`.

Comment: error : cannot convert from 'void' to 'dynamic'

Comment: You'll need to learn how delegates work.  Important to get ahead with C# programming.  You are already using one, EventHandler.  Use it again.  And no, don't call the Load event handler from a timer's Tick event, that makes no sense.

Comment: @John Hm. You could have made the title legible (or at the very least grammatical) in the process.

Comment: cannot convert from 'void' to 'dynamic' -> you are actually CALLING the Form1_Load method by specifying the arguments and the return type "void" doesn't fit into anything, not even a dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a delegate.  A delegate is essentially a method pointer which can be invoked later on.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Load();
        //this line 
        InitTimer(() => this.Form1_Load(sender,e));
    }

    public void InitTimer(Action target) 
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
        timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer1.Tick += (sender, e) => target();
        timer1.Interval = 5000; // in miliseconds
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

Comment: error : Delegate 'System.EventHandler' does not take 0 arguments

Comment: Doesn't work becuase "() =>" lambda doesn't have arguments whereas EventHandler has...

Answer (score 0):

```
#region Form1_Load()
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Load();
    //this line 
    InitTimer(OtherLoad);
}
#endregion

#region Timer()

private void OtherLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{...}

public void InitTimer(EventHandler _method)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
    timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer1.Tick += _method;
    timer1.Interval = 5000; // in miliseconds
    timer1.Start();
}
#endregion
```

IMPORTANT: make your timer call a different method (I used "OtherLoad") in order to avoid setting up the timer over and over again!